# Nested list or two dimensional array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array, nested-lists

I have a list of IP addresses. I need to store those IP addresses in a list or array (no duplicates allowed) and also store their count. 
For example I have

```
IP-1
IP-4
IP-7
IP-4
IP-2
IP-4
IP-2
```

This list is from a .txt file. I have multiple of those files, so I cant just put `list = [ [a,b], [c,d], [e,f] ]` like this in the code (I mean not to do it statically in code because for every .txt file the list would be different).
So in this list I have:
IP-1   1x
IP-4   3x
IP-7   1x
IP-2   2x
I have to store this somehow all in one list or array. For example like this:

```
list_of_ips_and_their_counts = [ [IP-1,1], [IP-4,3], [IP-7,1], [IP-9,2] ]
```

And now I have to search in this list/array for the IP with the highest number of occurrences and print it out. For example:

```
print("IP address " + the_ip + " occured " + number + " times.") # IP address IP-4 occured 3 times.
```

Im not sure how to store the IP addresses with their counts.

Comment: is it an array or a numpy array?

Comment: There is pandas Extension Array for storing IP addresses. It doesn't provide you with straight solution to store counts (you can use Pandas methods to do that), but it does have some nice IP-related methods https://github.com/ContinuumIO/cyberpandas

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count each `IP-{number}` line from the file:

```
from collections import Counter

with open("test.txt") as f:
    ip_counts = Counter(line.strip() for line in f)
    # Counter({'IP-4': 3, 'IP-2': 2, 'IP-1': 1, 'IP-7': 1})

    for ip_address, count in ip_counts.items():
        print("IP address %s occured %d times" % (ip_address, count))
```

**Output:**

```
IP address IP-1 occured 1 times
IP address IP-4 occured 3 times
IP address IP-7 occured 1 times
IP address IP-2 occured 2 times
```

You can also use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to count the lines as well if you prefer:

```
ip_counts = Counter(map(str.strip, f))
```

**Note:** [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) is used here to strip whitespace from the keys, such as converting `'IP-1\n'` to `IP-1`. This allows easier access to the keys in the future since you don't need to include whitespace.

If you want the maximum count, I would use [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) with [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
print(max(ip_counts.items(), key=itemgetter(1)))
# ('IP-4', 3)
```

Which returns the maximum tuple using the counts at index `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `np.argmax()`. That's for the second step of your question. But it's better that you ask one question per thread.

```
import numpy as np

result = ip[np.argmax(np.array(ip)[:, 1])]
print("IP address " + result[0] + " occured " + str(result[1]) + " times.")
```

```
Out[114]: IP address IP-4 occured 3 times.
```